# Crash when tapping on a WatchKit table row

Tags: swift, watchkit

I can display several table rows but when I tap one of those rows, the app crashes at `tableView.setNumberOfRows(:)`
I don't have any clue of what is going on. Any advise or tips are welcome. Thanks in advance.

[image: The error]
I don't understand why this happens because at the initial setup this code runs without errors. I get this error only when I tap one of the table rows.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: WKInterfaceTable!

 override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    // Configure interface objects here.

    loadTableData()
 }

 override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
 }

 override func didDeactivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    super.didDeactivate()
 }

 private func loadTableData() {
    tableView.setNumberOfRows(Categories.NotLocalizedCategories.count, withRowType: "RowController")

    for (index, category) in Categories.LocalizedCategories.enumerated() {
        if let rowController = tableView.rowController(at: index) as? RowController {
            rowController.rowLabel.setText(category)
        }
    }
 }

 override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {
    pushController(withName: "DetailInterfaceController", context: Categories.LocalizedCategories[rowIndex])
 }
}
```

Comment: You're most likely getting error at wrong line. If your problem happens on row tap, you should look at what happens in `didSelectRowAt` method. Try to comment out your current implementation (pushController(...)) and see if the problem is still there.

Comment: It doesn't crash when I remove pushController

Comment: Are you sure `tableView` is not nil?

Comment: Okay, now you know that the problem is in this method. Check what's happening when you accessing `Categories.LolcalizedCategories[rowIndex]`

Comment: It shows the category I've tapped. How can the tableView be nil? It's an IBOutlet

Comment: IBOutlets can be `nil` quite easily if you haven't hooked them up correctly to the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, either `tableView` or the context `Categories.LocalizedCategories[rowIndex]` is nil. Use the `if let` construct or the `guard` statement before passing the context.

Comment: It is not nil, it has a value according to the debugger

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because probably the **DetailInterfaceController** class, more precisely in the `awake` method, is being called `super.awake`, when doing this, the **InterfaceController** class will be instantiated again and the `awake` of this and everything inside is executed. Since the table reference for the storyboard is weak, its instance of the table will be null and then it will crash. One solution to this is to remove `super.awake` from the controllers you push.